# DSL preprocessor recursive macro

Tags: recursion, c-preprocessor, dsl

I use a domain specific language which has a preprocessor that's reminiscent of a C/C++ preprocessor but with differences, I hope it's self explanatory to show some examples, if not I can detail the specs.

```
#define VAL value
#macro MACRONAME($var1,$var2) ( ($var1) + ($var2))
```

The \ character permits to have a replacement or macro text that contains a newline. e.g.

```
#define VAL $var=1\
$var=2
```

will preprocess `VAL` into

```
$var=1
$var=2
```

Roughly I'm trying to generate the following

```
ADD 1 "SNA"
ADD 2 "FOO"
ADD 3 "BAR"
SHOW
$var_sna ASSIGN 1
$var_foo ASSIGN 2
$var_bar ASSIGN 3
```

basically SHOW uses the titles, shows a UI, gets back user input, then assign the fetched user input to the variables.

The problem would be that it's error prone, if you don't triple check the indices this will bite you in the ass and not assign the value you think to the variable you think, and you'll destroy your sample.

I managed to get something that looks like (this preprocessor permits nested evaluation)

```
#macro MACROADD($index,$variable,$title,$inside) ADD $index $title\
$inside\
$variable ASSIGN
```

which permits me to write

```
MACROADD(1,$var_bar,"BAR",MACROADD(2,$var_foo,"FOO",MACROADD(3,$var_sna,"SNA","SHOW")))
```

which expands to what I want. But it's really ugly, and will probably break when the length of the line goes to large values (ideally I'd like to be able to add as many variables as I want, within reasons ofc. Is there any tricks I'm missing?

Comment: Other than taking advantage of the (seeming) relationship between variable names and the strings associated with them, and assuming you can't access some global counter, there doesn't seem to be anything that can be removed from the expression you've written, suggesting there isn't much optimizing to be done.

Comment: The C word for ugly is `macro`. Don't worry about how it looks, just how it works. If your DSL macro processor is reasonably modern, I doubt it has any line length limits that will even come close to something you'd ever need to create.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved it by making my surrounding functions idempotent (I don't care if I "assign" before show or "add" after show) and accessing a global counter. Basically, this

```
ADD 1 "SNA"
$var_sna ASSIGN 1
ADD 2 "FOO"
$var_foo ASSIGN 2
ADD 3 "BAR"
$var_bar ASSIGN 3

SHOW

ADD 1 "SNA"    
$var_sna ASSIGN 1
ADD 2 "FOO"
$var_foo ASSIGN 2
ADD 3 "BAR"
$var_bar ASSIGN 3
```

works as well. To generate the indices I can access a global variable and add 1 at each "ADD ASSIGN"

```
#macro ADDASSIGN($variable,$title) ADD $title\
$variable ASSIGN $glob\
$glob=$glob+1

#macro STACK($inside,$element) $glob=1\
$element\
$inside\
$glob=1
$element
```

Then, I put the definition of the different steps in a define, therefore I can write:

```
#define RUN\
ADDASSIGN($var_sna,"HELLO THIS IS SNA")\
ADDASSIGN($var_foo,"HELLO FOO SPEAKING")\
ADDASSIGN($var_bar,"Meh, I AM BAR")\

STACK(SHOW,RUN)
```

and the preprocessor will generate the correct source code, and the original code contains the definitions in only one place, great success.